CalendarViewRequestBuilder - MSGraph - Python SDK - query parameter for start_date_time and end_date_time don't work
I've been playing around with the start_date_time and the end_date_time like this:
# Create GraphServiceClient
    graph_client = GraphServiceClient(credential, scopes)

    # Define date range for fetching events
    start_date = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
    end_date = start_date + timedelta(days=365)

    # Format dates correctly for the Graph API in ISO 8601 format
    start_date_str = start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
    end_date_str = end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

    # Insert colon in timezone offset
    start_date_str = start_date_str[:-2] + ":" + start_date_str[-2:]
    end_date_str = end_date_str[:-2] + ":" + end_date_str[-2:]
    print(f"Fetching events from {start_date_str} to {end_date_str}")

    # Set up the request configuration with query parameters as a dictionary
    query_params = CalendarViewRequestBuilder.CalendarViewRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        start_date_time=start_date_str,
        end_date_time=end_date_str,
        select=['subject', 'start', 'end'],
        top=100,
        orderby=['start/dateTime ASC'],
        #filter="contains(subject, 'from HR Works')"
    )


    headers = HeadersCollection()
    headers.add("Prefer", 'outlook.timezone="Europe/Berlin"')

    request_configuration = RequestConfiguration(
        query_parameters=query_params,
        headers=headers
    )

    all_events = []

    try:
        # Initial request
        events_page = await graph_client.users.by_user_id(user_id).calendars.by_calendar_id(calendar_id).events.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
...

It says then basically Fetching events from 2024-10-09T12:27:39+00:00 to 2025-10-09T12:27:39+00:00
but checking on them I see lot's of events from 2023?
for instance Absence from 2023-10-13T10:00:00.0000000 to 2023-10-13T11:00:00.0000000:
Where is my issue? I tried tweaking the timestamps, but nothing worked.
Also been diving into the official documentation which did not help:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/create-requests?tabs=python#use-select-to-control-the-properties-returned
EDIT: Using this query
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-06-14T00:00:00Z&endDateTime=2024-06-15T00:00:00Z in the GraphExplorer works, - meaning endDateTime and startDateTime parameters

Are you able to reproduce the issue in the Graph Explorer? Whether it's a SDK issue or server side issue.

@user2250152 I added more information, the Graph Explorer works.

Hardcoding those like,
        start_date_time='2023-06-14T00:00:00Z',
        end_date_time='2024-06-15T00:00:00Z',
        select=['subject', 'start', 'end'],
        top=100,
        orderby=['start/dateTime ASC'],
        #filter="contains(subject, 'from HR Works')"
    )``` those not work in my script.

Seems like you are calling wrong method. Checking your code
events_page = await graph_client.users.by_user_id(user_id).calendars.by_calendar_id(calendar_id).events.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)

you are calling the endpoint v1.0/users/{user_id}/calendars/{calendar_id}/events
For calendarView you need to call
result = await graph_client.users.by_user_id(user_id).calendars.by_calendar_id(calendar_id).calendar_view.get(request_configuration = request_configuration)

